# Выбор значений по условию

Tags: python, numpy

Есть массив порядка 100000 строк постоянно пересчитывается и дополняется.

```
array([[720, 4, 'A'],
       [710, 1, 'A'],
       [710, 2, 'B'],
       [700, 19, 'B'],
       [670, 1, 'B'],
       [700, 1, 'A'],
       [650, 1, 'B'],
       [650, 1, 'B'],
       [650, 1, 'A'],
       [650, 1, 'A'],
       [640, 1, 'A'],
       [630, 1, 'A'],
       [630, 1, 'A'],
       [610, 5, 'B'],
       [610, 1, 'B']], d_type=obgect)
```

Подскажите как из массива получить все строки со значением например (650 и 630)?

```
array([[650, 1, 'B'],
       [650, 1, 'B'],
       [650, 1, 'A'],
       [650, 1, 'A']], d_type=obgect)

array([[630, 1, 'A'],
       [630, 1, 'A']], d_type=obgect)
```

И возможно ли получить на выходе данные примерно такого вида (т.е. выбрать строки по условию из первого столбца, и в зависимости от значения третьего столбца (A или B) просуммировать значения 2-го столбца):

```
array([[650, 2, 'B'],
       [650, 2, 'A']], d_type=obgect)

array([[630, 2, 'A']], d_type=obgect)
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Массив отсортирован по первому значению или вразнобой? Если вразнобой, то скорее всего только перебором всего массива. А если отсортирован, то хотя бы методом половинного деления.

Comment: Массив не отсортирован. Т.е. получается что такой подход не практичен?

Comment: Нельзя ли использовать словарь?

Comment: Приму любые советы

Comment: @Tortuga Данные часто пересчитываются по отношению к тому как часто нужен к ним доступ?

Comment: Раз в 1 минуту.

Comment: @Tortuga Раз в минуту на таком относительно маленьком массиве - это редко. Как уже сказали можно делать словарь значение-индексы который обновлять после каждого пересчета и по нему достаточно быстро находить нужные элементы.

Comment: Спасибо! А с какой частотой возможно обновление данного массива без потери производительности?

Comment: Это уже нужно на практике тестировать чтобы найти баланс между скоростью доступа к данным и времени подготовки массива. У вас он обновляется редко, так что можно упираться в сторону подготовки массива после обновления. Но подготовка массива в 100тыс элементов на современном железе не думаю что в худшем случае займет более 1 секунды процессорного времени.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо за совет!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас разные типы данных в различных столбцах, то есть смысл использовать Pandas DataFrame вместо Numpy Array. DataFrame умеет работать со столбцами различных типов данныхю

Пример:

```
In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["col1", "col2", "col3"])

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
    col1  col2 col3
0    720     4    A
1    710     1    A
2    710     2    B
3    700    19    B
4    670     1    B
5    700     1    A
6    650     1    B
7    650     1    B
8    650     1    A
9    650     1    A
10   640     1    A
11   630     1    A
12   630     1    A
13   610     5    B
14   610     1    B

In [7]: df.query("col1 in [650, 630]")
Out[7]:
    col1  col2 col3
6    650     1    B
7    650     1    B
8    650     1    A
9    650     1    A
11   630     1    A
12   630     1    A
```

---

```
In [10]: df.query("col1 in [650, 630]").to_numpy()
Out[10]:
array([[650, 1, 'B'],
       [650, 1, 'B'],
       [650, 1, 'A'],
       [650, 1, 'A'],
       [630, 1, 'A'],
       [630, 1, 'A']], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2):

Исходные:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[720, 4, 'A'],
       [710, 1, 'A'],
       [710, 2, 'B'],
       [700, 19, 'B'],
       [670, 1, 'B'],
       [700, 1, 'A'],
       [650, 1, 'B'],
       [650, 1, 'B'],
       [650, 1, 'A'],
       [650, 1, 'A'],
       [640, 1, 'A'],
       [630, 1, 'A'],
       [630, 1, 'A'],
       [610, 5, 'B'],
       [610, 1, 'B']])
```

Преобразуем объектный тип в целочисленный:

```
s=a[:,0].astype(int)
```

теперь можно сделать так:

```
print(a[np.where((s==650)|(s==630))])
```

Получим:

```
[['650' '1' 'B']
 ['650' '1' 'B']
 ['650' '1' 'A']
 ['650' '1' 'A']
 ['630' '1' 'A']
 ['630' '1' 'A']]
```

Что касается второй части вопроса, то она мне не очень ясна.